# Meaning of Vim Mapping <A-x-Left><CR>

Tags: vim

I have seen this mapping in one vimrc file

```
  map <A-x-Left> :bprevious<CR>
```

But I don't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me neither. Vim doesn't support key chording, only simple combinations of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> with another (possibly <kbd>Shift</kbd>-ed) key. `:help key-notation` is the corresponding reference.

What was probably meant is this:

```
map <A-x><Left> :bprevious<CR>
```

Which can be triggered by first pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> together, followed by <kbd>←</kbd>.

And this [should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Answer (score 1):

`<A-` is the Alt key, so `<A-x-Left>` means Alt + x + left arrow. You can read more on key notation in vim's help: `:help key-notation`.